# IncompatibleClassChangeError when testing SpringBoot JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, testing, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to make integration tests for testing spring jpa interfaces.

I have got the error `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.springframework.test.context.TestContext, but class was expected` and i am unsure why this is the case. I am practically following [this tutorial](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-integration-testing/#comment-1376758).

**StackTrace**

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.springframework.test.context.TestContext, but class was expected
at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:84)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

**Application.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

  // ------------------------
  // PRIVATE FIELDS
  // ------------------------

  // An autogenerated id (unique for each user in the db)
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  // The user's email
  @NotNull
  private String email;

  // The user's name
  @NotNull
  private String name;

  // ------------------------
  // PUBLIC METHODS
  // ------------------------

  public User() { }

  public User(long id) { 
    this.id = id;
  }

  public User(String email, String name) {
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
  }

  // Getter and setter methods

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(long value) {
    this.id = value;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String value) {
    this.email = value;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String value) {
    this.name = value;
  }

} // class User
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

**UserController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository ur;

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getName(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        User a = ur.findOne(id);
        return a.getName();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{name}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String setUser(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        User usr = new User("email@email.com", name);
        ur.save(usr);
        return name + "Created";
    }
}
```

**user-entries.xml**

```
<dataset>
    <users id="#{new Long(1)}"
           email="jon@email.com"
           name="Jon"/>
    <users id="#{new Long(2)}"
           email="mike@email.com"
           name="Mike"/>
</dataset>
```

**UserTest.java**

```
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableWithSize;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener;

import com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener;
import com.github.springtestdbunit.annotation.DatabaseSetup;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PersistenceContext.class})
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})
@DatabaseSetup("users-entries.xml")
public class UserTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Test
    public void findbyName_usingName() {
        Iterable<User> searchResults = userRepo.findAll();
        assertThat(searchResults, IsIterableWithSize.<User>iterableWithSize(2));    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================

# Set here configurations for the database connection

# Connection url for the database "netgloo_blog"
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = blah

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.elderstudios</groupId>
    <artifactId>watchmaker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>qqq</name>
    <description>Timesheet System</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

If anyone can spot the root cause of this error, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Nearly always means that you have mismatched versions. Post your POM or Gradle build file. Note that that tutorial is three years old, and you can autogenerate a skeleton project at https://start.spring.io.

Comment: @chrylis I have added my pom.xml, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `com.github.springtestdbunit` dependency version `1.0.0` requires (has defined in it's pom - see relevant github page ):
`<spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>`

However `org.springframework.boot` dependency version `1.3.2.RELEASE` requires:
`<spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>`

So you have two different spring versions in your application.

To be compatible you can upgrade your `com.github.springtestdbunit` to version `1.2.1` which is the latest and requires spring `4.1.4.RELEASE` (https://github.com/springtestdbunit/spring-test-dbunit/blob/spring-test-dbunit-1.2.1/spring-test-dbunit/pom.xml) and downgrade your `org.springframework.boot` version to `1.2.1.RELEASE` which also uses spring `4.1.4.RELEASE` (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml).

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: There's no need to downgrade to Spring Boot 1.2.1. Spring 4.2.x is backwards compatible with 4.1.x so only upgrading spring-test-dbunit should be sufficient.